# Programmatically Add a Control to a TabPage

Tags: c#, richtextbox, tabpage

All, I want to add a custom `RichTextBox` to a WinForm `TabPage`. I have tried various things illustrated by the code below

```
TabPage tmpTabPage = new TabPage("Test");
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tmpTabPage);

CustomRichTextBox tmpRichTextBox = new CustomRichTextBox();
tmpRichTextBox.LoadFile(@"F:\aaData\IPACostData\R14TData\ACT0\1CALAEOSAudit_log.rtxt");

// Attempted FIX.
tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
tabControl1.TabPages["Test"].Controls.Add(tmpRichTextBox); // This throws a NullReferenceException??
tabControl1.ResumeLayout();

tmpRichTextBox.Parent = this.tabControl1.TabPages["test"];

tmpRichTextBox.WordWrap = tmpRichTextBox.DetectUrls = false;
tmpRichTextBox.Font = new Font("Consolas", 7.8f); 

tmpRichTextBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tmpRichTextBox.BringToFront();
```

Before I added the "aAttempted FIX", the code would run without exception but the `CustomRichTextBox` would not appear. Now I get the `NullReferenceException` and I am confused over both situations. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The solution below coupled with that above is all I needed/have...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're really missing is setting the "Name" property for your TabPage variable.
The string you're passing to TabPage's constructor is only setting the TabPage.Text property.

Just add the following code after instantiating your TabPage and you should be fine:

```
TabPage tmpTabPage = new TabPage("Test");
tmpTabPage.Name = "Test"
// Rest of your code here
```

The reason you are getting the NullReferenceException is because the following code:

```
tabControl1.TabPages["Test"]
```

is not returning a reference to the TabPage, because the TabPage's "Name" property was not set.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this by adding the tmpRichTextBox to tmpTabPage and then adding tmpTabPage to tabControl1

```
        TabPage tmpTabPage = new TabPage("Test");
        CustomRichTextBox tmpRichTextBox = new CustomRichTextBox();
        tmpRichTextBox.LoadFile(@"F:\aaData\IPACostData\R14TData\ACT0\1CALAEOSAudit_log.rtxt");

        // Attempted FIX. 
        tmpTabPage.SuspendLayout();
        tmpTabPage.Controls.Add(tmpRichTextBox); // This throws a NullReferenceException?? 
        tmpTabPage.ResumeLayout();

        tmpRichTextBox.Parent = tmpTabPage;

        tmpRichTextBox.WordWrap = tmpRichTextBox.DetectUrls = false;
        tmpRichTextBox.Font = new Font("Consolas", 7.8f);

        tmpRichTextBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tmpRichTextBox.BringToFront();

        //tmpTabPage.Controls.Add(tmpRichTextBox);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tmpTabPage);
```

Comment: Still get the `NullReferenceException`.